# python fastest way to divide multi dimensional list

Tags: python, arrays, cpython

dealing with optimize dividing 2 dimensional list
a = [[0, 2169, 5454], [1878, 0, 454]]
by an integer value, to get an integer result:
right now I have a wildly inefficient for loop - I have read some of the documentation about mapping to int, and using list comprehension, but struggling to understand how to make it work for a two dimensional list

```
   for row in range(0, len(a)):
      for col in range(0, len(a[row])):
          a[row][col] = int(a[row][col] / 600)
```

Comment: The only way to get a significant improvement would be with numpy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need the range loops, you can use a list comp:

```
a[:] = [[ele // 600 for ele in sub] for sub in a]
```

`a[:]` will change the original list the same as your code is doing just with the efficiency of a list comp.  If you want any real further significant improvement you should look at [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/).

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(a)

a //=  600

print(a)
[[0 3 9]
 [3 0 0]]
```